# mcAfee antivirus immediately delete the .exe file when we run our program in VS Code

Tags: antivirus, virus

[image]mcAfee  antivirus immediately delete the .exe file when we run our program in VS Code saying it a virus.
What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Adding an exclusion?

Comment: Many AV will falsely assume you unpopular .exe that is not signed is likely a virus. I just exclude my entire programming folder where all my projects exist to avoid this issue.

Comment: The current answer raises a good point. I don't generally download prebuilt libraries (build everything from source) so my excluding of the entire projects tree is relatively safe. If you however do download dlls you may want to scan before putting them in such a location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is for personal use:

- Add the compile folder to the exclusion list (might need system restart)
- Add your whole personal projects folder to the exclusion list. Take care, don't use in this folder code/projects downloaded from the internet that you don't trust.
- Use another antivirus (including windows built-in)

If your program is for public distribution/distribution within a company:

- Submit a report to the antivirus makers